# Similar programs to Tomboy, but with reminders

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, tomboy

I love Tomboy, it is a great program, but it is missing a little bit what I need.

Let's say I want to clean my room (yes, lame example, but can't create something better), so I write me a note "Clean a room" and that note is shown every 15 minutes let's say until I delete that note or mark it is finished.

Or let's say I create a note that in two days there is my mother's birthday and it reminds me every 6 hours and stop reminding me it in two days.

Well, I search for similar programs, do you know any?

Thank you very much and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fork of Tomboy called GTG (Getting Things Gnome) that aims to help the user getting things done. I am not certain if it includes alarms or periodic notifications like you request, but it might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin in Tomboy called 'Reminder', now included (but not enabled) by default. To enable (under Ubuntu 11.10), go to Preferences, Add-ins, and look under Tools. To get a note to open automatically at a given day or time, write in the note that date or time preceded by a `!`.

Examples:  `!2 Nov` , `!2 November 2014`, `!20:30`, etc.